# Meaning/Structure of "Es mag so paradox anmuten"

Tags: translation, meaning, german-to-english, sentence-structure

> Das Führen von Kriegen ist keinesfalls ein unverbrüchliches Naturgesetz, sondern ein Kulturprodukt, sozusagen ein Kollateralschaden des zivilisatorischen Prozesses. **Und so paradox es angesichts grausiger Aktualitäten auch anmuten mag**: Die Erde ist im Lauf der vergangenen Jahrtausende ein immer friedlicherer Ort geworden.

How would you translate the sentence in bold? I've never seen a structure "Es mag ... paradox anmuten" before, with "mag" as an auxiliary verb. What are the possible meanings when we use "mag" as an auxiliary verb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For my understanding as a German native speaker the *mögen* in *Es mag paradox anmuten...* has two purposes at the same time:

- It implies an **uncertainty** about the rest: Maybe it seems to be paradoxical *to you* but it need not seem paradoxical *to everyone*.
  <sup>**EDIT:** As some have noted in the comments, instead of uncertainty the phrase could communicate **irrelevance**: It does not matter if it seems paradoxical or not because...</sup>
- It makes the whole phrase a **concessive** clause (Konzessivsatz/-konstruktion) as if a *zwar* was present (*Zwar mutet es paradox an, aber...*). It may seem paradoxical BUT IT ISN'T. So everything following the colon may seem paradoxical but is not. In my mind the *X mag Y sein*-construction provokes a big *ABER*.

There are other concessive constructions (with *obwohl, zwar, obschon...*) but they do not include the first bullet part of uncertainty. If the phrase was *Zwar mutet es paradox an, aber die Erde...*, then it would be certain that it seems paradoxical to everyone.

To make things easier I use another example sentence to compare a normal statement with a concessive construction using **zwar** and a concessive construction using **mögen**:

- **"Sarah findet ihn nett."** = normal statement
- **"Sarah findet ihn zwar nett..."** = provokes a continuation with "but" (**"..aber ich finde ihn nicht nett."**); additionally it is certain that Sarah likes him.
- **Sarah mag ihn nett finden...** = provokes a continuation with "but" (**"..aber ich finde ihn nicht nett."**); additionally it is uncertain if Sarah aktually likes him.

<sup>**EDIT:** For my taste, both the *zwar*-phrase and the *mögen*-phrase contain the same degree of irrelevance but not the same degree of uncertainty.</sup>

Comment: That "uncertainty" meaning isn't always present: "Sarah mag ihn nett finden ..." can also mean "I _know_ that Sarah likes him, but I _don't care_". Also in the phrase in question, it isn't uncertainty that's being expressed, but rather surprise:  "You won't expect that fact, it might even appear paradoxical to you, but I tell you it is true nevertheless."

Comment: @Matthias: Für mich schwingt da auf jeden Fall Unsicherheit mit. Wenn ich sage "Sarah mag ihn nett finden...", dann stelle ich das in Frage und meine implizit "Was? Wirklich? Sarah findet ihn nett? Okay, das mag so sein(=vielleicht ist das ja wirklich so, ich bleibe aber skeptisch und kann gar nicht richtig glauben, dass sie ihn mag), aber..."

Comment: "X ist ein Chaot." - "Aber Sarah findet ihn nett!" - "Sarah mag ihn nett finden oder nicht, trotzdem ist er ein Chaot." Hier verschwindet die Unsicherheit, und es bleibt nur Irrelevanz.

Comment: @Ingo: Hmmm... In dem Kontext bleibt für mein persönliches Empfinden immer noch eine Nuance von Unsicherheit und Infragestellen. Für mich klingt es so, als wolle der Sprecher eigentlich eine Diskussion darüber führen, ob Sarah den X nett findet oder nicht, er das Diskutieren dann aber sein lässt, weil es -- stimmt, du hast recht! -- irrelevant ist. Ich weiß aber gerade nicht, wie ich die Irrelevanz noch einpflegen soll.

Comment: Chris: Das _kann_ so sein, aber worum es mir (und wohl auch @Ingo) geht: es _muß_ nicht sein. "Mögen" kann benutzt werden, um ohne jede Unsicherheit, aber eben mit einem Ton von Irrelevanz etwas einzuräumen. Siehe dazu auch die Links zu Duden und Canoo in meiner Antwort.

Comment: @Matthias Richtig. Und ich würde sogar so weit gehen, daß in dem Beispiel des OP dieses "mag" sogar als eine Art höfliches "trotzdem" gebraucht wird: "Ich weiß, daß angesichts der grausigen Aktualitäten viele das Gegenteil denken, aber trotzdem verhält es sich so: Die Erde ist ... ein freidlicherer Ort geworden."

Answer (score 3):

The phrase could be translated as:

> And as paradoxical as it might appear in the face of horrible recent news: ...

"Mag" is a conjugated form of "mögen", a modal verb (that can also be used as a main verb). As you can see from its entry in the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/moegen) it can be used to express quite a few different things. I prefer the summary they give at [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/VollHilfModal/moegen.html):

- The main use of "mögen" is to express a **wish**, most frequently by
  using the conjunctive form "möchten" - so frequently, that one might
  be tempted to regard "möchten" as an [independent verb](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15311/does-the-verb-m%C3%B6chten-exist).
- Another use is to express that **someone likes to do something**
  (they use "Lust" at Canoo, but I'm not sure about a matching English
  noun).
- The function that you can find in the phrase in your question is
  **concession** or **granting**: "yes, I admit that it will sound paradoxical to many readers ...".
- You can use "mögen" to express **uncertainty**, bu according to Canoo it
  is obsolecent.
- And finally, you can use it to politely form an **indirect request**.

Answer (score 0):

"mag" is a modal (mögen); it is ethymologically the same as "may", yet be careful, as both languages use it quite differently.
I'll try a (somewhat free) translation: "As strange as it may seem in the face of current, brutal events: during the course of past milennia, Earth became a more peaceful place"

Note that "may" must not be used to denote permission:

> You **may** open the window
>   #Du **magst** das Fenster öffnen (instead: Du **darfst** (dürfen) das Fenster öffnen)

Comment: "Du magst das Fenster öffnen, aber dein Asthma wird dadurch nicht besser werden." => "Selbst wenn du das Fenster öffnetest, ..."

Comment: Die Raute soll heißen: anderer Sinn als im Englischen, mögen heißt nicht dürfen, wohingegen im Englischen may mögen (als Modalverb) und dürfen bedeuten kann.

Comment: Als ob *dürfen* wirklich besser wäre, sofern es als Subjunktiv von *darben* abstammte (also etwa *#du brauchst das Fenster öffnen*; so tatsächlich im Französischen "avoir *besoin*" ca. *nötig haben*, vgl *Besorgnis*???)

Comment: PS: dort, im Französischen, aber vielleicht auch zu unterscheiden. Ich mag mich irren. Ich weiß es wirklich nicht.