# Welchen Kasus verlangt "ich möchte"?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-case

Ich habe bemerkt, dass auf *möchten* sowohl Akkusativ als auch Dativ folgen können, z. B. liefert eine Google-Suche:

- Google-Suche nach "ich möchte einem": 36.500 Ergebnisse
- Google-Suche nach "ich möchte einen": 539.000 Ergebnisse

Ich glaube, dass 36.500 Ergebnisse genug sind, um eine Frage zu stellen. Wie lautet die korrekte Kasus-Verwendung nach *ich möchte*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vorweg: Bei *möchten* handelt es sich nicht um ein eigenständiges Verb, sondern formal um eine Konjunktiv-II-Form von *mögen*. Deshalb gibt es (noch) keinen Infinitiv *möchten*.

Zu deiner Frage: Wenn du *ich möchte* mit einem Objekt verwenden willst, dann wird dieses Objekt im **Akkusativ** gebraucht:

- Ich möchte einen Hamburger.
- Ich möchte eine Pizza.
- Ich möchte ein Eis.

Dass deine Suche nach *ich möchte einem* (mit Dativ) so viele Treffer liefert, liegt daran, dass auf *ich möchte* auch ein Infinitiv folgen kann (modaler Gebrauch):

- Ich möchte spielen.
- Ich möchte jemandem eine E-Mail schreiben.
- Ich möchte dir ein Buch schenken.

Hier werden die Dativ-Formen *jemandem* und *dir* nicht von *ich möchte* verlangt, sondern von den Verben im Infinitiv, die folgen:
*jemandem ... schreiben*, denn derjenige, dem geschrieben wird, steht im Dativ.
*dir ... schenken*, denn *schenken* benutzt den Dativ um den Beschenkten auszudrücken.

Wiederhole ich deine Google-Suche, erhalte ich Treffer wie:

- Ich möchte einem Bieter ein Angebot unterbreiten. (denn: *jemandem etwas unterbreiten*)
- Ich möchte einem Mädchen etwas Schönes schreiben. (denn: *jemandem etwas schreiben*)
- Ich möchte einem Freund Angelschnüre kaufen. (denn: *jemandem etwas kaufen*)

Comment: I didn't expect such a detailed answer. I want to thank you for that. 
I want to thank as well the other users, that make the effort to help me out.

Answer (score 5):

"Möchten" as a full verb governs accusative and cannot take an indirect object. As it is a modal verb it can be combined with other verbs that might require Dative. This dative object often comes right after the conjugated form of "möchten" but it is not linked to it at all. This is why you cannot compare the search results directly.

> **Ich möchte einen** Tee.
> I'd like a tea.
>
> **Ich möchte einem** Mann etwas geben.
> I'd like to give something to a man.

The "meinem" in the second example belongs to "geben".

EDIT: Sorry for the English. I didn't pay attention to the language of the question.

Answer (score 3):

"Möchten" als ein "normales" Verb benötigt ein direktes / Akkusativ-Objekt:

> Ich möchte einen Kaffee.

(Wobei "möchten" streng genommen nur ein Konjunktiv von "mögen" ist, siehe [Does the verb "möchten" exist?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15311/does-the-verb-m%C3%B6chten-exist))

"Möchten" kann aber auch als ein modales Verb gebraucht werden. In diesem Fall richtet sich der Kasus der Objekte wie bei allen modalen Verben nach dem Hauptverb.

> Ich möchte einem Freund etwas mitteilen. (*einem Freund* ist indirektes Objekt, also Dativ, zu *mitteilen*)
>
> Ich möchte einen Freund anrufen. (*einen Freund* ist direktes Objekt, also Akkusativ, zu *anrufen*)

Comment: Thanks for the clearance. I thought that it was something related to the nature of the desired object.