# Welche defektiven Verben gibt es in der deutschen Sprache?

Tags: verb, conjugation, curiosity

Ich bin neugierig, welche defektiven Verben (auch: unvollständige Verben; engl.: [defective verb](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb)) es in der deutschen Sprache gibt und konnte im Internet keine erschöpfenden Listen finden. Andererseits konnte ich bisher nur eine systematische Gruppe und zwei individuelle Verben finden (siehe meine Antwort), was mich zu der Annahme veranlasst, dass diese Frage hinreichend eng für diese Seite ist.

#### Kriterien

Ein *defektives Verb* ist ein Verb, von dem nicht alle Konjugationsformen existieren. Dabei sollen für diese Frage folgende Kriterien gelten:

- Es reicht nicht, wenn Verbformen fehlen, an denen kein semantischer Bedarf besteht. Zum Beispiel fehlt den meisten intransitiven Verben (wie *sein, laufen, schlafen*) das Passiv und unpersönlichen Verben (wie *mangeln, schwanen, weihnachten*) die erste und zweite Person, weil diese semantisch keinen Sinn ergeben.
- Das Verb muss produktiv genutzt werden und eindeutig als solches zu erkennen sein. Ein Gegenbeispiel hierzu ist *verschollen,* das aus einem Partizip II hervorgegangen ist, aber heutzutage ununterscheidbar von einem Adjektiv ist (und so wird es auch [vom Duden geführt](//www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verschollen)); das entsprechende Verb wird also nicht mehr produktiv genutzt.
- Die fehlenden Formen brauchen nur praktisch tot sein, d.h., selbst die meisten sprachlich versierten Teilhaber der deutschen Sprache nutzen oder kennen diese nicht.

*Da diese Frage nach einer kleinen Liste fragt, hat diese nur eine Antwort, die ein [Community Wiki](//meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1229/2594) ist. Statt neue Antworten zu verfassen, editiert bitte die existierende Antwort.*

Comment: Die ersten und zweite Person von Regnen ergeben semantisch sehr wohl Sinn, und sie existieren auch: Treffen sich zwei Wolken. Sagt die eine zur anderen: »Regnest du heute?« Sagt die andere zur einen: »Ja, ich regne heute.« In der Literatur kommt es immer wieder vor, dass eigentlich unbelebte Dinge in der Ich-Form sprechen. Mir fällt da als Beispiel der Lindberghflug von Brecht und Weill ein, in dem u.a. der Schneesturm, der Nebel, das Wasser und der Motor des Flugzeugs zu Wort kommen. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Flug_der_Lindberghs.

Comment: Auch die Anbetung ist denkbar, hier wird "regnen" in der zweiten Person benötigt: »Oh Himmel, bitte regne!«

Comment: Passiv für »gehen«: »Was? Frau Müller arbeitet hier nicht mehr? Warum ist sie gegangen?« - »Sie ist nicht freiwillig gegangen, **sie wurde gegangen.**«

Comment: Die Formen *fehlen* meiner Ansicht nicht, sondern sie ergeben in den meisten Fällen keinen Sinn und finden deswegen keine - oder seltene - Anwendung. Huberts Beispiel ist ein schönes dafür. Und natürlich kann man "Ich wurde gewesen" oder "Ich habe geregnet" *bilden*. Die grammatischen Regeln und dei entsprechenden Verbformen dafür existieren. Und die Grammatik interessiert der **Sinn** nunmal überhaupt nicht. Ich finde eine solche Liste nicht zielführend.

Comment: @tofro: Deswegen habe ich solche Fälle ja auch explizit von dieser Frage **ausgeschlossen**.

Comment: Es gibt *Konjugationsregeln* und weitere Bildungsregeln für Verbformen und selbst ein (üblicherweise nicht existierendes) Verb wie z.B. *fröben* kann nach diesen Regeln alle Formen annehmen - **Keine** davon ist nutzbar, weil keine davon semantisch einen Sinn ergibt. Grammatisch mag jede dieser Formen trotzdem korrekt sein.

Comment: Und auch von *weihnachten* kann ich ohne Probleme eine Form der ersten Person bilden: »Ich weihnachte dir gleich was!«

Comment: @tofro: Tut mir leid, aber ich verstehe absolut nicht, worauf Du hinausmöchtest.

Comment: Du gehst davon aus, dass es Verben gibt, von denen nicht alle Konjugationsformen existieren. Und ich behaupte, dass es, weil es Regeln gibt, wie sie zu bilden sind, man alle Konjugationsformen *bilden kann*. Sie werden nur bisweilen nicht verwendet, weil sie nicht in jedem Fall sinnvoll sind.. Daher gibt es, zumindestens aus *grammatischer* Sicht, keine solchen Verben. Aus *semantischer* Sicht mag es sie geben.

Comment: Forts.: Der Ausdruck "weil aus semantischer Sicht kein Bedarf besteht" in deiner Frage ist mir dafür zu wacklig - Es gibt im Deutschen sehr viele Wörter, für die das zutreffen würde - für das Verb "kehren" *besteht aus semantischer Sicht kein Bedarf*, weil es ja "fegen" gibt.

Comment: @tofro: *[…] weil es Regeln gibt, wie sie zu bilden sind, man alle Konjugationsformen* bilden kann. *Daher gibt es, zumindestens aus* grammatischer *Sicht, keine solchen Verben.* –  So einfach ist das nicht. Es kann zum Beispiel sein, dass eine nach grammatischen Regeln geformte Form gemeinhin als grammatisch falsch empfunden wird (z. B. *ehebrich).* Außerdem gibt es keine Möglichkeit von einer Imperfekt- oder Partizip-II-Form (z. B. *auserkoren*) eindeutig auf die Präsens-Formen zurückzuschließen. Siehe auch [die Beispiele aus anderen Sprachen](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb).

Comment: *Der Ausdruck "weil aus semantischer Sicht kein Bedarf besteht" in deiner Frage ist mir dafür zu wacklig* – Da es hier nur um einen Ausschluss von möglichen Antworten geht, sehe ich da kein Problem. Es finden sich halt im Internet ein paar Seiten, die zum Beispiel unpersönliche Verben als defektive Verben ansehen. Um ähnlichen Antworten zuvorzukommen und eine wacklige Frage zu vermeiden, habe ich diesen Fall explizit ausgeschlossen. Seine genaue Definition spielt dafür zum Glück keine Rolle.

Comment: *ehebrich!* - Wo ist das Problem? Imperativ. Dieser Befehl dürfte einigermaßen selten gegeben werden, aber das Verb und seine Verbform **gibt es**. *auserkiesen* **gibt es auch**. Ich befürchte, du suchst eine *Liste von Verben mit extrem selten verwendeten Verbformen*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54559/discussion-between-wrzlprmft-and-tofro).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Rückbildungen, Konversionen zusammengesetzer Substantive und kopulative Verb-Verb-Komposita

Die Unterscheidung der drei Fälle ist vor allem eine etymologische und daher nebensächlich für diese Frage. In jedem Fall handelt es sich um zusammengesetzte Verben, dessen letzter Teil einem normalen Verb entspricht und die entweder in Anlehnung an ein bereits existierendes Substantiv oder aus der Kombination zweier gleichwertiger Verben gebildet wurden, z. B.:

> Uraufführung → uraufführen
>   Bruchrechnung → bruchrechnen
>   Ehebruch → ehebrechen
>   ziehen + schleifen → ziehschleifen

Diese Verben sind häufig defektiv: Meistens ist nur der Infinitiv und die Partizipien nutzbar.

**Bekräftigung**

Aus *Grundzüge der Morphologie des Deutschen* von Hilke Elsen:

> Ein wichtiger Hinweis auf eine Rückbildung ist meist das Meiden finiter
>   Flexionsformen. […] Die Defektivität ist natürlich kein eindeutiges Kriterium, da auch Konversionen hin und wieder und Kopulativkomposita meist ein unvollständiges Verbparadigma aufweisen.

## *mögen* und *möchte*

Die Konjunktiv-II-Formen des Verbs *mögen* sind eigentlich *möchte, möchtest* usw. Diese haben aber eine eigene Bedeutung entwickelt (nämlich *wünschen* statt *gernhaben/bevorzugen*) und werden in dieser Bedeutung wie ein Indikativverb genutzt. Dieses neue Verb ist defektiv, da es nur die Präsens-Aktiv-Indikativ-Formen besitzt. Gleichzeitig hat das Verb *mögen* seinen Konjunktiv II verloren (zumindest bei den meisten Sprechern), der aber durch die *würde*-Form ersetzt werden kann. (Mehr dazu [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15311/2594).)

**Bekräftigung**

Aus *Einführung in die grammatische Beschreibung des Deutschen* von Roland Schäfer:

> Das Verb zu *ich möchte* ist ein historisch aus dem Konjunktiv Präteritum von *mögen* hervorgegangenes defektives Verb […]. Es hat nur finite Präsensformen, keinen Konjunktiv und auch keine infiniten Formen.

## *kiesen* und Ableitungen

Formen wie *erkor* oder *auserkoren* sind eigentlich Vergangenheitsformen bzw. Partizip II von *erkiesen* bzw. *auserkiesen,* die aber kaum jemand kennt oder nutzt. Damit handelt es sich hierbei praktisch um ein defektives Verb.

**Bekräftigung**

Aus dem [Duden-Eintrag zu *auserkiesen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auserkiesen):

> Perfektbildung mit »hat«; im Infinitiv und im Präsens Aktiv ungebräuchlich

Comment: Nur nebenbei: Im Sächsischen ist *möchten* immernoch der Konjunktiv von *mögen*: "Die Direktorin sagt, du möchtest mal zu ihr gehen."

Comment: »Nachdem sie den Teppich **gestaubsaugt** hatte, ging Val mit Rosa und Bobby nach draußen ...« aus *Die Reise mit der gestohlenen Bibliothek* von D. Whitehouse, ISBN 9783608501483. Oder »Tom hatte den Frühstückstisch abgeräumt, das Geschirr abgewaschen, **gestaubsaugt** und gebügelt.« aus *Nordmond* von S. Dünschede, ISBN 9783899777253

Comment: »Staubsaugst du bitte die Wohnung?« »Ich sauge staub« – kann so gehört werden; es existiert mE sogar ein Zwiebelfisch dazu. Ebenso halte ich *ehebrechen* für ein vollständig ausgebildetes Verb das lediglich aus semantischen Gründen selten verwendet wird. *Bruchrechnen* würde ich persönlich gelten lassen, das mag in anderen Gegenden Deutschlands, Österreichs oder der Schweiz anders sein. *Mögen* und *möchten* weise ich zurück; wer *möchten* für ein eigenes Verb hält, hat Grammatik nicht begriffen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Okay, und was widerlegt das jetzt? Ich habe *staubsaugen* angeführt, weil es eines der geläufigsten rückgebildeten Verben ist. Unter anderem deswegen hat es mehr Formen als die meisten solchen Verben. Im Imperativ mutet es zumindest mir immer noch seltsam an – vielleicht in ein paar Jahren nicht mehr.

Comment: @Jan: Was hältst Du von »ehebrich nicht«? Ist semantisch ziemlich nah an »du sollst nicht ehebrechen« dran. Außerdem [dokumentiert der Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ehebrechen), dass nur Infinitiv und Partizip gebräuchlich sind.

Comment: @Jan: Mögen *und* möchten *weise ich zurück; wer* möchten *für ein eigenes Verb hält, hat Grammatik nicht begriffen.* – Kannst Du das näher ausführen?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Das beweist, dass *staubsaugen* kein gutes Beispiel für ein Wort ist, von dem nur Infinitiv und das Partizip I nutzbar sind.

Comment: @Jan: Wer *möchten* für ein eigenes Verb hält, hat begriffen, dass sich *möchten* in der Alltagssprache längst von *mögen* getrennt und emanzipiert hat: *Ich möchte ein Eis. Ilse hat gestern ein Eis gemocht aber nicht bekommen. Glaubst du, dass du morgen ein Eis möchten wirst?* Ich gebe zu: Kann heftige Anfälle von Sprachekel hervorrufen, wird aber trotzdem gelegentlich so verwendet.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: *Das beweist, dass* staubsaugen *kein gutes Beispiel für ein Wort ist, von dem nur Infinitiv und das Partizip I nutzbar sind.* – Was ich auch niemals behauptet habe..

Comment: *Auserkiesen* ist doch offens Präteritum; Vgl. *erwiesen*. Nenne bitte auch nur ein anderes Verb auf *-iesen*, mit dazugehörigem *-oren* (welches existieren mag, aber evtl erst spät dem Vorbild nach dazu erkoren wurde). Wegen *Kur*, *Kurfürst* etc. ist Einfluss von Latein oder sonstiges denkbar, dass nicht zur Alltagssprache gehörte.

Comment: @vectory: Wenn Du an der Darstellung des Dudens (und anderer Wörterbücher) zweifeln möchtest, meinetwegen, aber das ist genug Stoff für eine eigene Frage. So oder so, worauf möchtest Du im Hinblick auf diese Frage bzw. Antwort hinaus?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft mit Verlaub, ich dachte du hättest eine Rechtfertigung für die Aussage parat, nicht nur eine Vorschrift. Man sollte schon verstehen, was man abschreibt, oder wenn nicht, die Kritik würdigen.

Comment: @vectory: Erstmal haben die meisten Wörterbücher den Anspruch, die Sprache zu dokumentieren, und nicht vorzuschreiben. Dann kann ich einen besseren Beleg als eine Wörterbuchreferenz nur liefern, indem ich eine Korpusanalyse o. Ä. durchführe, was den Rahmen hier komplett sprengt. Du kannst aber gerne eine eigene Frage stellen, warum der Dudeneintrag für dieses Verb so ist, wie er ist, o. Ä. Schließlich: Wenn Du meinst, dass ich den Duden falsch verstanden habe, sage mir bitte, wo; dann kann ich darauf vielleicht eingehen.

Comment: [Bitte schön](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49810/auskiesen-auserkiesen-vs-auserkoren). Hatte es eilig und kein konkretes Bild außer meiner schon hier gestellten Frage vor Augen, sorry. Unser kleiner Exkurs könnte dann bis zum Beweis des Gegenteils gelöscht werde. Nur nochmal zur Deutlichkeit, der Nachfrage wegen: eine Erklärung bedürfte über den Duden-Beleg hinaus auch einer Herleitung der Grammatischen Form, um meiner Nachfrage gerecht zu werden. Dafür würde mir zuerst auch das aufzeigen einer Gruppe gleicher Formen genügen.

Comment: @vectory: *Hatte es eilig* – Ehrlich gesagt hättest Du die Frage wahrscheinlich später in Ruhe gestellt. Es war ja nun wirklich nicht dringend.