# auskiesen, auserkiesen vs auserkoren

Tags: etymology

Ist *auserkiesen* als Infinitiv-Form eines verbes mit *auserkoren* als entsprechendem Präteritum bzw. Partizip zu erklären? Diese Behauptung steht immerhin im Duden [auserkiesen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auserkiesen).

Das Wort ist veraltet, insofern hilft mein Sprachgefühl nicht weiter. Die Behauptung finde ich nur deshalb nicht überzeugend, da mir kein anderes Verb nach dem gleichen Schema einfällt. Viel eher wirkt *kiesen* wie ein passender Reim auf *wiesen* < *weisen*.

Ich kenne nur *sich auskesen* oder [*auskäsen*--das ist mundartlich nicht mehr zu unterscheiden-- in der Bedeutung "sich entscheiden, in die Gänge kommen" (ref [auskäsen](http://www.sachsenwelt.de/sachsen/mundart/woerterbuch-a.html) auf Sächsisch).

Eine Herleitung, die mir zugetragen wurde, ist für meine Begriffe nicht überzeugend, *auskiesen* [sic!] käme von der Praxis, ein Bauvorhaben durch ein Kiesbett zu beginnen und so die Stelle des Bau's festzulegen, also auszusuchen. Das würde auf Indo-Europäisch zurückgehen, insofern die Wurzel mit der Deutung "to [choose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/choose)" rekonstruiert wird. Da das nicht meine eigene Idee ist, zweifle ich sie reflexartig an. Tatsächlich gibt es [auskiesen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auskiesen), "Kies aus einer Grube nehmen".

Zu [kiesen](https://dwds.de/wb/kiesen) und [Kür](https://dwds.de/wb/K%C3%BCr) steht einiges bei Pfeifer, via DWDS -- Verwandschaft besteht mit En. *chose, choice*. Was sagt das über den Vokal? *Kosen, Liebkosen, sorgen*? Für *[Kür](https://dwds.de/wb/K%C3%BCr)*, *Kur* bzw *erkoren* bin ich da nicht so sicher. En. *chores*, "die Kür --erst die Pflicht, dann das Vergnügen"? Ein Lateinischer oder alt-ererbter Einfluss schwer nachvollziehbarer Gestalt wäre auch interessant. Dazu zählt auch der *Kurfürsten*.

Die Frage ist, ob *kies-* und *kor-* eher in ursprünglich unterschiedlichen Wurzeln zu suchen ist, oder wie der *grammatische Wechsel* von *s*~*r* sonst zu erklären sei. Da David Vogt auf *gewesen*~*war*, bzw. En. *was* und *were*, etc. hinweist, wäre die Frage, ob hierfür die gleiche Erklärung dienen kann. Zudem fällt auch das Pronomen *wir* < PGem *wiz als wohl eher unregelmäßige Lautverschiebung auf.

Comment: Ohne jetzt irgendetwas über die Etymologie von _auserkiesen_ zu wissen (oder es auch nur jemals zuvor im infinitiv gesehen zu haben), kann ich doch mit ziemlicher Gewissheit sagen, dass die Ähnlichkeit mit _auskiesen_ reiner Zufall ist.

Comment: @GrottenOlm beachte auch *aussuchen*, *ausgesucht* (nicht *-er-*), sowie, was ich ziemlich witzig finde, *auskäsen* (*käs‘dich aus, entscheide dich, komm aus'm Knick*; ob e oder ä ist in der regionalen Aussprache nicht mehr zu unterscheiden ). Ab wann eine rein zufällige Verwechslung etimologisch wird, ist gerade die Frage.

Comment: Eine ausgekieste Frage.

Comment: Ich finde Deine Frage ziemlich verwirrend: 1) Viele Sätze scheinen kaputt, insbesondere gibt es viele unverständliche eingestreute *bzw.* 2) Große Teile sind im Gedankenstrom geschrieben. 3) Du springst zwischen *auskiesen* und *auserkiesen,* ohne dass klar wird, warum. Zum Beispiel im ersten Satz: Warum sollte *auserkoren* das Partizip von *auskiesen* sein? Das behauptet niemand, so weit ich weiß. 4) Was genau zweifelst Du an und was möchtest Du wissen? Welche Antwort bzw. welcher Beleg könnten Deine Skepsis befriedigen?

Comment: Die Frage ist sehr verwirrend formuliert, hat aber einen spannenden Kern: Wie kommt man drauf, dass der Infinitiv zum Partizip "auserkoren" "auserkiesen" sein soll. Ich fände das Verb "kören" (dass es gibt) viel naheliegender.

Answer (score 3):

Das Verb *kiesen* gehörte zur mhd. Ablautklasse II (Paul/Wiehl/Grosse, Mhd. Gr., § 246) wie auch *gießen, genießen, schießen, schließen, fließen*. Die Alternation *s* – *r* ist ein nicht ausgeglichener grammatischer Wechsel (man vergleiche *war – gewesen*).

Ausgeglichen wurde der grammatische Wechsel zwischen Sg. Prät. einerseits und Pl. Prät. und Part. Prät. andererseits bei: *verlôs, verlurn, verlorn* (nhd. *verlieren*); *vrôs, vrurn, gevrorn* (nhd. frieren).<sup>[1](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=verlieren) [2](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=frieren)</sup>

Von *kiesen* haben nur partizipiale und präteritale Formen (*erkoren, auserkoren*) überlebt.

Comment: Besser noch *niesen*, ohne *ß*. Bei *gewesen*~*war* handelt es sich aber um das zusammenfallen zweier unterschiedlicher Wurzeln; Man spricht in diesem Fall von einem Paradigma, nicht wahr? Darauf zielte die Frage tatsächlich ab. Was bedeutet *ausgeglichen* in *ausgeglichener grammatischer Wechsel*? Sollte ich vielleicht mal ersuchen, würde aber die Antwort bereichern. Zu *verlieren* wird auch *verletzen* und sicher auch *verlassen* gestellt (*etwas verlegen* vermutlich nicht, aber wer weiß, vgl. *lesen* und Lt. *ligo* bzw. *lego*). Diese werden doch nicht als Formen von *verlieren* gezählt.

Comment: Danke jedenfalls, es dürfte wohl die traditionelle Antwort sein.

Comment: Unterschiedliche Wurzeln sind *sein* und *wesen*. Mhd. *was, waren, gewesen* (Sg. Prät., Pl. Prät, Part. Prät) gehören zusammen. Unter *Ausgleich* versteht man Vereinheitlichung des Paradigmas zugunsten eines Stammes. Also nicht mehr Sg. Prät. vs. Pl. Prät. *zôch, zugen* sondern einfach *zog(en)*.

Comment: Die Frage wurde angepasst. Der grammatische Wechsel ist soweit unklar, doch aber gerade das komische an der Sache.

Answer (score 2):

Ich beschränke mich hier auf die Eingangsfrage:

> *Ist auskiesen als Infinitiv-Form eines verbes [sic.] zu erklären, bzw. auserkiesen und ist auserkor- das entsprechende Präteritum bzw. Partizip dazu?*

Ja, so ist es – fast. Die Frage handelt tatsächlich von zwei unterschiedlichen Verben: *auskiesen* und *auserkiesen*. An die Grundform *kiesen* wurden lediglich die Präfixe *aus-* und *er-*, beziehungsweise das Doppelpräfix *auser-* gehängt. Zudem sind zusammengesetzte Verben mit *aus-* normalerweise trennbar. Das Präteritum von *auserkiesen* ist demnach nicht *auserkor*, sondern *erkor aus*.

Das Flexionsschema ist eigentlich analog zu anderen Verben, wie ich anhand des schwachen Verbs *wählen* verdeutlichen möchte:

> **Grundform**
>   
>   wählen – wählte – gewählt
>
> **Präfix *aus-***
>   
>   auswählen – wählte aus – ausgewählt
>
> **Präfix *er-***
>   
>   erwählen – erwählte – erwählt
>
> **Doppelpräfix *auser-***
>   
>   auserwählen – erwählte aus – auserwählt

Bei *kiesen* ist das nicht anders:

> **Grundform**
>   
>   kiesen – kor – gekoren
>
> **Präfix *aus-***
>   
>   auskiesen – kor aus – ausgekoren
>
> **Präfix *er-***
>   
>   erkiesen – erkor – erkoren
>
> **Doppelpräfix *auser-***
>   
>   auserkiesen – erkor aus – auserkoren

Der einzige Unterschied zu *wählen* ist, dass es sich bei *kiesen* um ein starkes Verb handelt und dass es deshalb seinen Stammvokal ändert. Aber auch das ist nichts Ungewöhnliches (vgl. *gießen*, *genießen*, u.a.).

Comment: Wenn du mit *wählen* auf *erwägen* hinaus willst, würde das halbwegs einleuchten, aber ein einfacher Verweiß auf schwache Verben erklärt noch keinen Wechsel zwischen s und r. Ob *auskiesen* u.U. homophon sein könnte, kann ein einfacher Blick ins Wörterbuch nicht ausschließen--gemeint ist ein homophones \*auskiesen "aussuchen".

Comment: @vectory Wovon reden Sie? Ich jedenfalls weder von einem „[...] Wechsel zwischen s und r“, noch von Homophonie. Ich hatte mich allein auf die Eingangsfrage beschränkt (das steht aber auch ganz oben), und zwar weil ich mit dem Rest Ihrer Frage überhaupt nichts anfangen kann.

Comment: Dann hätte die Antwort auch einfach "Es ist ein unregelmäßíges Verb" lauten können, oder? Der Kern der Frage sucht nach einer Erklärung der Unregelmäßigkeit.

Comment: Die Vergangenheitsform von *auskiesen* "etwas bestimmtes mit Kies anstellen", dürfte übrigens einfach *gekiest* lauten, insofern das Bsp. noch in Bezug steht zur Eingangsaussage

Comment: Häh? Inwiefern soll die Information, dass _kiesen_ ein unregelmäßiges Verb ist, die Frage beantworten, ob _"[...] auskiesen als Infinitiv-Form eines verbes [sic.] zu erklären [ist]"_? Und wenn das tatsächlich die gesuchte Antwort war, hätte Ihre Frage auch einfach _"Ist kiesen ein unregelmäßiges Verb"_ lauten können. Der Kern Ihrer Frage ist nämlich nur schwer zu erfassen.

Comment: @vectory Ja, _kiesen_ im Sinne von "mit Kies belegen" würde ich als schwaches Verb verwenden: _kiesen_ – _kieste_ – _gekiest_.

Comment: Ich drückte mich ungeschickt aus. Bitte vielmals um Entschuldigung. Ich meinte, die Antwort sagt nichts weiter aus, und könnte daher auf diesen einen Satz reduziert werden. Das wäre aber keine gute Antwort, denn der Kern der Frage such nach einer Rechtfertigung für jenen Satz, einer Erklärung. Auch das habe ich äußerst unglücklich formuliert.

Comment: Darum steht es Ihnen ja auch frei, diejenige Antwort zu erkiesen – was Sie ja bereits getan haben –, die den Kern Ihrer Frage am besten beantwortet. :-)

Comment: Um es noch mal deutlich zu sagen, um nicht undankbar zu erscheinen, wenn der Wechsel von "kies-" zu "kor-" als Prämisse angenommen wird und daher keiner weiteren Erklärung bedarf, kann es nicht die Schlussfolgerung sein, sonst wäre es ein Zirkelschluss. Eine andere Schlussfolgerung lässt die Antwort aber nicht erkennen, also ist es ein Zirkelschluss, egal was die Frage eigentlich war. Naja gut, das stimmt nicht, da steht auch noch eine Schlussfolgerung, aber dass die Änderung des Stammvokals der einzige Unterschied wäre, ist offensichtlich falsch.