# Are there any defective verbs in German? Are there any that lack an infinitive?

Tags: verb

German is my work language. I was trying to think today of any verbs that lack an infinitive, like "can", "shall" ... and other modal verbs in English. "zu können" is absolutely everyday. I don't believe i can think of any at all.

More generally: are there any verbs that lack parts, tenses or persons.

Or perhaps there are verbs that only exist in passive or active voices.

I am interested in any of the above phenomena.

One could argue "regnen" lacks all but the third person, but i don't find the idea of saying something like "wir regnen" or "sie regnet" poetically or metaphorically particularly weird. Like, it would sound unusual and immediately evoke a poetic image, but it wouldn't sound like a syntax "error" to me. Or am i wrong?

Comment: I'd like you to specify what do you mean in the "zu können" sentence.

Comment: Same question in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35085/35111

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Welche defektiven Verben gibt es in der deutschen Sprache?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35085/welche-defektiven-verben-gibt-es-in-der-deutschen-sprache)

Comment: Die Wolke - sie regnet ...

Comment: Please note, the related question is asked and answered in German so it can't be cited as a duplicate (resulting the question being closed). There seems to be some disagreement on this in Meta, but my understanding is [this post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/807/43989) is considered the current policy.

Comment: @c.p. "to can", i.e. the infinitive, doesn't exist in English, except in my own dialect influenced by my grandfather's scots dialect. But, "ich muss nach London, um den australischen Corona-Repatriierungsflug nehmen zu können" is a totally everyday thing to say.

Comment: @SeleneRoutley I agree. But the Ersatzinfinitive in *zu können* is not the same as infinity (*können*).

Comment: @c.p. okay, i'd count them as the same, because they both take the infinitve verb form, but one could also easily say "Ich muss mehr Sprachen sprechen können" - that one's not too far from everyday speech even for a nonnative speaker like me.

Answer (score 3):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_defective_verbs) has a category for defective verbs, but at the moment only five are listed and those aren't very common. If you're looking for something similar to English "can", modals/auxiliaries which don't have independent meanings, then German does not have them. German does have one or two verbs along the lines of English "quoth", which were once full verbs but all but a few inflections have fallen out of use. Wikipedia mentions *erkiesen* which is only available in past participle and past tense. As with "quoth", I don't think it's a verb you need to worry about as a learner; you might hear it occasionally in a historical/sci-fi/fantasy TV show or movie, but you'd get odd looks if you started using it amongst your friends. The Wiktionary category also lists verbs which, because of their meaning, are only usable in the third person, but you said you don't want to count those. I agree that *Ich bin eine Wolke und ich regne* is metaphorical but still grammatically correct.

Comment: Thanks for that. As i suspected there are very, very few examples in German. "erkiesen" is quite fascinating considering it's cognate with O.E. "cesan" which became "choose", a nondefective verb in English! Thanks for a most fascinating example.

Answer (score 2):

The only verb I know which comes close to a defective verb is *erkiesen* (to choose). Only the perfect participle *erkoren* is still (rarely) used today. I think most Germans will not know what it means if they come across the infinitive (if they can't guess it from context).

Comment: Erkeisen is most fascinating indeed, considering it's cognate with O.E. "cesan" which became "choose", a nondefective verb in English!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it counts, but:

The Konjunktiv II "möchten" of the verb "mögen" has acquired a meaning of its own ("to want"), while the original verb has nearly lost this meaning, and is mostly used with the meaning "to like".

So, one could argue that "möchten" has become a defective verb.

Comment: Whilst i wouldn't count this as quite an example, it is indeed fascinating because it shows how verbs can become defective with evolving usage. Rather cool!

Answer (score -1):

"sein" doesn`t have a passive voice, same goes for reflexive verbs.

Comment: No German verb requires a "zu" to form an infinitive. The infinitive and zu + Infinitive are two different forms.

Comment: The second part of the answer seems to refer to a construct called *Ersatzinfinitiv*, see [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/111/1696) to a related question. While you raise a valid point concerning reflexive verbs, I consider *werden* as passive form of *sein*.

Comment: I agree with both comments. But I'd say that one cannot blame the response if the answer was not timely closed (it's confusing due to "zu können"). Wenn man eine Frage beantwortet, geht man manchmal davon aus, dass die Frage gut gestellt ist.

Comment: @guidot One really wouldn`t use werden as a passive voice of sein, at least not in any regular way.

Comment: Actually, you're right about the reflexives having no passive voice when they exist only as a reflexive verb. The same goes for most intransitives like gehen - they can't have a passive form, but the past participle, which is how passive is formed, exists, so one could say that all the inflexions of gehen nonetheless exist.