# Difference between möchten and mochten

Tags: meaning, difference

sometimes I misspell `möchten` with `mochten` but vocabulary doesn't complain. I tried to find out what that word means, but I'm not sure if I get it right. Is the `mochten` past form of `möchten`?

Could you please provide me with example?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15311/does-the-verb-m%c3%b6chten-exist

Comment: And: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mochten

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, both exist, but *möchten* is not the verb in present. *Möchten* is Konjunktiv II of *mögen*, and *mochten* its Präteritum (a past). For instance:

> Niemand **mochte** den Mangel an Recherche. **Möchtest** du bitte nächstes Mal ein Wörterbuch nachschlagen?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that even if as you rightly say "ich möchte" is Konjunktiv II of "mögen" technically, it has somewhat evolved into a verb of its own that most native speakers would assume to be the simple present of "möchten" (which doesn't exist) and use like that. (Next to no native speaker would realize when asking for a roll in the bakery with "ich möchte ein Brötchen, bitte" he just used Konjunktiv II)

Comment: In Sachsen sagt man auch: "Richte ihm bitte von mir aus, er möchte mal herkommen." Hier wird der Konjunktiv noch deutlicher.

Comment: Your sentence with "mochte" sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @CarstenS Ok. Could you say what precisely sounds or is wrong?

Comment: It is past tense of "niemand mag diese Frage beantworten", and except for the Konjunktiv II case the construction "mögen + Infinitv" to me seems not to be fully standard. What works for me: "Niemand mochte den Kuchen. Magst Du ihn? Möchtest Du ein Stück?". Here the "mochte" has the same meaning as the "magst", which is different from "möchtest". But maybe I am too strict here.

Comment: Hierzulande (NRW) habe ich "magst du mir deine Telefonnummer geben?" gehört, da wo ich anstelle *mögen*, etwa *wolllen* ewartet habe. Es ist gut zu wissen, dass es nicht nur mir kommisch klingt. Hier wollte ich auch nicht direkt schreiben: *niemand mochte die Frage*, daher der aktuelle Satz.

Comment: *Mögen* zu verwenden statt *Wollen* oder *Können*, kenne ich vor allem von Pädagogen: "Magst du mir helfen? Magst du mir mal den Stift geben?"